# M1 Mac Think Or Swim Native Installation

Tags: macos, installation, terminal

Im trying to install Think or Swim on my M1 Max MacBook Pro using this guide

https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkorswim/comments/oojac1/guide_running_thinkorswim_natively_on_apple/

On step 6 I keep getting this error, any help appreciated thank you !

> java -jar launcher.jar
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)at com.devexperts.jnlp.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:30)at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.devexperts.jnlp.utils.URLManager$1 (in unnamed module u/0x182a48cb) cannot access class sun.security.util.HostnameChecker (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.util to unnamed module u/0x182a48cbat com.devexperts.jnlp.utils.URLManager$1.verify(URLManager.java:48)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:653)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:594)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)at com.devexperts.jnlp.updater.HttpResponse.(HttpResponse.java:26)at com.devexperts.jnlp.updater.HttpRequest.doRequest(HttpRequest.java:82)at com.devexperts.jnlp.updater.HttpRequest.doGetRequest(HttpRequest.java:63)at com.devexperts.jnlp.utils.Utils.getVersion(Utils.java:201)at com.devexperts.jnlp.updater.ModuleManager.isUptodate(ModuleManager.java:363)at com.devexperts.jnlp.UpdateManager.isModuleUptodate(UpdateManager.java:154)at com.devexperts.jnlp.UpdateManager.main(UpdateManager.java:442)... 6 more

Answer (score 0):

Before step 6, do this;

Type "**cd thinkorswim**"

This tells the computer where the folder is I believe.

---

Next problem you may encounter, is finding the file path for the usergui. Change the 1970.0.70 to the folder after "usergui".

EG:

"sudo cp ~/Downloads/jna-platform.jar ~/Downloads/thinkorswim/usergui/1970.0.70/jna-platform-3.5.2.jar"

Make sure you go to wherever your file is (I kept mine in downloads permanently) downloads-> thinkorswim-> usergui-> 1971.1.2 is the file path for mine.

"sudo cp ~/Downloads/jna-platform.jar ~/Downloads/thinkorswim/usergui/1971.1.2/jna-platform-3.5.2.jar"

---

Once you sort everything out, keep these 3 commands close:

1. cd ~/Downloads (or wherever the folder is)
2. cd thinkorswim
3. sudo java -jar launcher.jar

This is how you're going to relaunch TOS from now onwards.

Enjoy the smoothness. It's truly significant.